# Why didn't Tao define $0^c$ for $c>0?$

Tags: real-analysis, definition, exponentiation

In course of reading Real Exponentiation from Analysis I: Terence Tao, I noted that the author did not define $0^c$ where $c>0$, thought he defined $0^0$ and $x^c$ for all $x>0,\ c\in\mathbb{R}$. However the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_zero) gives definition of $0^c$ for $c>0$.

Why didn't Tao define $0^c$ for $c>0?$ Is there any text that covers such case?

N.B. Even in this text: springer.com/in/book/9781493927654 authors did the same.

Comment: Even in this text: http://www.springer.com/in/book/9781493927654 authors did the same.

Comment: It could easily be a typo, or an oversight. The Wikipedia article is correct, and I have never seen anyone use any version of exponentiation other than the one where $0^c=0$ for all real $c$.

Comment: @pseudocydonia Not for $c\le0$.

Comment: So in that book the series $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$ is undefined at $x=0?$

Comment: $0^n,0^{1/n}$ is defined for $n\in\mathbb N.$ Only that much.

Comment: @pseudocydonia $0^0$ is sometimes defined as $1$ and sometimes as $0$ depending on the context.